# How to manipulate anonymous function parameters with a userscript/tampermonkey? [change Mastodon notification sound]

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts, mastodon

I am not a frontend or web developer, this is a private thing.

I wish to change the default notification sound on the mastodon web instance i use.

In order to do that, it appears to be necessary to manipulate the hardcoded Audio object creation in the script.

The original source at mastodon/app/javascript/mastodon/middleware/sounds.js is this:

```
export default function soundsMiddleware() {
  const soundCache = {
    boop: createAudio([
      {
        src: '/sounds/boop.ogg',
        type: 'audio/ogg',
      },
      {
        src: '/sounds/boop.mp3',
        type: 'audio/mpeg',
      },
    ]),
  };

  return () => next => action => {
    if (action.meta && action.meta.sound && soundCache[action.meta.sound]) {
      play(soundCache[action.meta.sound]);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}
```

As we can see there are hardcoded pathnames for the sound used in the notification feature. Digging into the generated JavaScript, i found that this fragment gets processed into the following fragment within [https://instance.url/packs/js/common-[hash].js](https://instance.url/packs/js/common-%5Bhash%5D.js) which is in turn part of a dispatch routine using more anonymous functions in a map, and.... Yeah.

```
function(){const e={boop:qt([{src:"/sounds/boop.ogg",type:"audio/ogg"},{src:"/sounds/boop.mp3",type:"audio/mpeg"}])};
```

My questions are thus: Is this even feasible? How would you approach it? What alternatives should I consider?

Comment: You can probably intercept the network request they're using to load the sound and substitute it with something else. In Tampermonkey you can also do it using its webRequest feature.

Comment: ([`GM_webRequest` "docs"](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/397#issuecomment-299949037) for reference)